# Please help me to solve unconfirmed transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I tried to send a bitcoin transfer and it is still unconfirmed and I have my block chain account set to "use recommended fee" by default. Can anyone help me get this confirmed or teach me how to get it confirm (or how to raised the tx fee to get it be confirmed faster? Many thanks for your kind support.

Here is the link:
https://blockchain.info/tx/c6816a387cb0ca8e33bb7b200372ce05919f6003034faaeecb1f72436827b32b

Comment: The fee is around 10 satoshi's per byte, which is quite low, it may take some time but it will almost certainly confirm eventually. I'd guess it will be within a few days, but that depends on the transaction load.

Comment: accelerated. will be confirmed very soon

Answer (score 1):

Patience grasshopper!  According to 21's block confirmation estimator with your 10.21 sat/byte fee your tx will likely confirm in the next ~3-32 blocks.  For future reference though, if you would like to add a higher fee check into using recently added RBF (Replace By Fee) functionality that was recently added to bitcoin core and multiple wallets.  Here is a bitcointalk thread that discusses this at length for numerous wallet clients:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1802212.0

Comment: Also possible [CPFP](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/cpfp), it's usually more expensive than RBF but works even with transactions that you did not prepare to be replaced.